# BSOD STOP 0x000000F4

Tags: windows-7, bsod, sata

I have searched pretty extensively for a solution to this issue without resolve, so I was hoping that someone here could help me.

Problem:
After having used my new PC since May of this year, I started get this BSOD STOP 0x000000F4 immediately after the Windows loading screen about a week ago.  I run a dual boot between Linux and Windows, and Linux runs fine (what I'm typing on now).

To remedy I have tried the following:

- Clearing CMOS
- Updating BIOs to latest version
- Putting RAM in different slots
- Running memcheck and Windows Memory Check without detectable issue
- Running full SMART diagnostics on my harddrive to detect any flags that would indicate pre-failure status.
- Unplugging and plugging back in all SATA connections.  The harddrive is correctly in the master SATA controller port.
- Running Windows 7 Repair; doing system restore
- Deleting the pagefile.sys file

To be clear, I cannot even get into Safe Mode.  Apparently Windows was not configured to create minidumps upon realization of a BSOD, so I have no reasonable debug information to use to diagnose the issue.  Even if I did, I'm not aware of any utility I can use on linux to look at windows symbol dumps.

My hardware:

- ASROCK P67 Extreme Mobo
- Intel Core i5 2500K
- Samsung Spinpoint - 1 TB
- EVGA nVidia Geforce 560 Ti

As I said, I was running on this setup for about six months before this happened.  Nothing has changed on either the hardware or software level.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware using a boot cd?...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your memory speed in BIOS - it could be set to a speed that doesn't match your actual memory. I had this problem with a P67 board. BIOS was setting the speed at 1333 but the memory was 1600. Failing that, try swapping the memory out for a different stick to try and rule out faulty RAM.

Answer (score 0):

For a dump view utility use Nirsoft Blue Screen Viewer.  As for the rest... you have covered good stuff.  Any chance you have tried a Windows Repair?

Comment: Yes.  Microsoft apparently removed the option to run a repair install in favor of their startup repair tool, which is useless.  I cannot view any Minidumps because my computer was never configured to produce them, and I can't figure out how to change this through the Recovery Console.